# Type checker problem while writing a parser in racket

Tags: parsing, racket, typed-racket

I hava  a language PLANG that supports evaluating a
polynomial on a sequence of points (numbers). 
 the language  allows  expressions of the
form {{    … } {  … }} where all  and all  are
valid AE expressions (and both  ≥ 1 and ℓ ≥ 1).

I was trying to write a parse for this language here is what I have so far:

```
(define-type PLANG
  [Poly (Listof AE) (Listof AE)])
 (define-type AE
 [Num Number]
 [Add AE AE]
 [Sub AE AE]
 [Mul AE AE]
 [Div AE AE])

 (: parse-sexpr : Sexpr -> AE)
 ;; to convert s-expressions into AEs
 (define (parse-sexpr sexpr)
 (match sexpr
 [(number: n) (Num n)]
 [(list '+ lhs rhs) (Add (parse-sexpr lhs)
 (parse-sexpr rhs))]
 [(list '- lhs rhs) (Sub (parse-sexpr lhs)
 (parse-sexpr rhs))]
 [(list '* lhs rhs) (Mul (parse-sexpr lhs)
 (parse-sexpr rhs))]
 [(list '/ lhs rhs) (Div (parse-sexpr lhs)
 (parse-sexpr rhs))]
[else (error 'parse-sexpr "bad syntax in ~s"
 sexpr)]))

 (: parse : String -> PLANG)
 ;; parses a string containing a PLANG expression to a PLANG AST

 (define (parse str)
 (let ([code (string->sexpr str)])
 (parse-sexpr (code) )))



(test (parse "{{poly 1 2 3} {1 2 3}}")
 => (Poly (list (Num 1) (Num 2) (Num 3))
 (list (Num 1) (Num 2) (Num 3))))
(test (parse "{{poly } {1 2} }") 
 =error> "parse: at least one coefficient is
 required in ((poly) (1 2))")
(test (parse "{{poly 1 2} {} }")
 =error> "parse: at least one point is
 required in ((poly 1 2) ())")
```

when I'm trying to make it run I get the errors:

```
Type Checker: Cannot apply expression of type (U (Listof Sexpr) Boolean Real String Symbol), since it is not a function type in: (code)
. Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: Poly
  given: AE in: (parse-sexpr (code))
. Type Checker: Summary: 2 errors encountered in:
  (code)
  (parse-sexpr (code))
>
```

Any help  would be appreciated..

Comment: Are you using `#lang typed/racket`, or a language like it such as `#lang pl` or `#lang plai-typed`?

Comment: @AlexKnauth I'm using #lang pl

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is caused by an extra pair of parentheses. Keep in mind that in Racket, Typed Racket, and `#lang pl`, parentheses usually mean function application like this:

```
(function argument ...)
```

So when you write `(code)`, it tries to interpret `code` as a function, to call it with zero arguments.

You can fix this problem by replacing `(code)` with `code` in the body of the `parse` function.

```
(define (parse str)
  (let ([code (string->sexpr str)])
    (parse-sexpr code)))
```

The second problem happens because you specified that the `parse` function should return a `PLANG`, but it instead returns the result of `parse-sexpr` which returns an `AE`.

Another way of wording this is that you've implemented parsing for `AE`s, but not for `PLANG`s.

Comment: So I should add another parsing Implementation to convert the AE to PLANG?